# error 6632 jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

We are using *iReport 5* and *JasperReports Server 5*.  W have a report based on a *MySQL Stored procedure* that runs fine in the Designer, but throws a 6632 error running from the server.

The stored procedure accepts 3 parameters, I have set the parameters up as Input Controls on the server.  When we run the report from the server, we get the following error:

```
2013-04-16 22:20:00,968 ERROR Validator,pool-1-thread-9:493 - Invalid SQL:An error has occurred. 
Please contact your system administrator. (6632), SQL: call sp_fasb(?, ?, ?)
2013-04-16 22:20:00,968 ERROR AsyncJasperPrintAccessor,pool-1-thread-9:258 - Error during report execution
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSSecurityException: An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.validators.Validator.validateSQL(Validator.java:494)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:167)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:859)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:821)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1622)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1005)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In previous versions, this was reported as needing a regular expression for the SQL Validation property, or needing to lengthen the size of the number of characters in the underlying query, both of which we have attempted without success.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to SQL Injection secuirty related fix in 4.5

1. Please check that the report you are running does not contain the SQL query which has comments in start of query. As of 4.5, such queries will not be allowed , as they pose SQL Injection security risk.
2. can u please add exact error log from the "jasperserver.log" to get the exact error message. Then we will be able to provide you the correct workaround by configuring the secuirty related properties file
3. As easy workaround, you can also go to /jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/security-config.properties file and then disable the secuirty for SQL Injection:-

   ```
     security.validation.sql.on=true
   ```

   to

   ```
     security.validation.sql.on=false
   ```

Comment: I'm assuming that the first line is what you need, but I removed the comments from the stored procedure; that did not work.  We then disabled the SQL injection security as suggested and that allowed the report to run.

Comment: 2013-04-16 22:20:00,968 ERROR Validator,pool-1-thread-9:493 - Invalid SQL:An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632), SQL: call sp_fasb(?, ?, ?)

Comment: How did you disable the security for SQL Injection? To disable see the updated answer.

Comment: We changed the security.validation.sql.on to false, and the report runs, however this leaves our server installation vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jaspersoft Studio 6.1.1 and trying to get a report compatible for Jasper Server 5.5.0, I found that all I had to do was add language="SQL" as a property for queryString and then the 6632 error stopped.  I'm not sure why that was missing, but it was in my case.

```
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[call sp_fasb(?, ?, ?)]]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: is your report working fine after adding language="SQL"?

Comment: @AnirudhNegi - Yes.